# Trying to test PhpSpreadsheet Hello World program, getting an error saying permission denied

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have an app that is based on PHP version 8. I've recently installed the PHP package PhpSpreadsheet through Composer and, following the Getting Started section in the documentation, I'm trying to run the provided Hello World program, which should write a new XLSX document:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello_world.xlsx');
```

The only thing I have changed is the require statement, which has been changed to reflect the relative location of the file and which appears to be working without issue, and the file name of the excel document, changing it to "hello_world" instead of "hello world". But when I execute this program, I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(hello_world.xlsx): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\BaseWriter.php on line 111
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could not open file "hello_world.xlsx" for writing. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\BaseWriter.php:113
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php(504): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\BaseWriter->openFileHandle('hello_world.xls...')
> #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\Services\export-excel-cg.php(14): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx->save('hello_world.xls...')
> #2 {main}
> thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\BaseWriter.php on line 113

I'm not sure what's going on here, and it seems odd that the program that the documentation provides to verify that it works doesn't work. Is there anyone familiar with PhpSpreadsheet that can spot what's going wrong here?

Here's the documentation for reference: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#getting-started

Comment: it looks like the file 'hello_world.xlsx' is already open, try to close it before running the script or change the name of the output file.

Comment: I can verify that hello_world.xlsx was not open or in use when the program was run. Can you clarify what you mean when you say change the name of the output file?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. While I checked the permissions on the files, I did not check the permissions on the folder and it turns out my account did not have full permissions for the *folder* it was in. After updating those and giving my account full permissions, it is working as expected now.